# MaterialUI - Styling an Input's placeholder text

Tags: css, material-ui

I've attempted a few stack overflow answers for some similar Material UI questions, but none of the solutions seem to work for my case.

I have an Input component with placeholder text. I want to style the placeholder text's size and font family. Right now I'm just inline styling through inputProps on the component. Here's my code:

```
<Input
          inputProps={{
            classes: {
              fullWidth: {fontFamily: 'Open Sans', fontSize: 18.9}
            }
          }}
          fullWidth={true}
          placeholder="Business Email Address"
          onChange={this._onChange}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styled components in es6 you can use this, create constant with style

```
//this out side the class
const inputStyle = {
  fontFamily: 'Open Sans', 
  fontSize: 18.9px
};

<Input
   style={inputStyle}
   fullWidth={true}
   placeholder="Business Email Address"
   onChange={this._onChange}
/>
```

I hope this work with you

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to follow the Material-UI docs and overlooked this simple solution

Answer (score 4):

I know I am answering an old question, but...

Another option is to use the '&' selector in your styles.

```
'& ::placeholder': {
   //Styles go here...
}
```

This will directly impact the placeholder text.